# Normal map not showing up in render

Tags: node-editor, normals, normal-map

I am following this tutorial about making an anvil, and I was first stuck on the normal map, but i was able to fix that. I had forgotten to UV unwrap my low poly mesh. But now i have another problem. I am configering nodes to the Principle Shader, and my Normal map does not show up at all. If i lower the strength of displacement node, you can sort of see it, but it still isn't enough. You would have to look really hard.

This is the normal map:
[image]

I am unable to post the screenshot with the other nodes applied, but basically the dents up top dont show up. or any other for that matter. I know that you can see it because earlier, the normal map did show up, and when I increased the strength to 10.000, i was able to see the dents, but also that i did not shade smooth either of the models. I have also tried to change the textures, but no luck.
I fixed the normal map from being stretched and ridged, but now it wont show up.

Here is the blend file:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/ipftp0xshhfe5js/Anvil12.blend/file
Here are the materials:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/zxhdi3o10fgnocw/MetalCorrodedHeavy001_%282%29.zip/file
Here is the normal map i had baked:
https://www.mediafire.com/view/2t92heq3fy03u9i/Normal1.png/file

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please pack your images into the file (File > External Data > Pack All Into Blend)

Comment: @moonboots sorry, i was unaware of that. Ill update the post as well. https://www.mediafire.com/file/ipftp0xshhfe5js/Anvil12.blend/file

Comment: still no image here, maybe my Blender bugs? I don't know...

Comment: That is odd, but I'll post two separate links i guess. @moonboots

Comment: @moonboots I updated the link, to the .blend again, but in case it doesn't work there are two links for the normal map and the textures. Thank you for going through this trouble.

Comment: it works fine, whether with bump + normal or normal alone: https://zupimages.net/up/20/22/2ea2.jpg

Comment: @moonboots Even in cycles? I had a bunch of nodes connected to it, with an HDR and all, but it doesn't show up like yours.

Comment: actually i can't try eevee on my computer but i test with 2.80

Comment: @moonboots I am using 2.87, but idk if that makes a difference. You just opened the file and tested it out?

Comment: I had to load your normal and bump images, I unplugged the other ones

Comment: Did it work with the other nodes plugged for you? I did what you said, only having the normal and bump nodes connected, and i get the same result you did. I lowered the strength of the bump node, but even then, with all the other nodes, you can barely see the normal. Is there a way to fix that? I changed the strength for the bump and whatever else i can, but if there is a way for me to fix it without having to do that, it would be cool to know.

Comment: you can increase the bump map effect with a Math node (multiply mode), but I don't think you can increase the effect of the Normal map (except with its own strength). Maybe there's a normal bake issue with 2.8, I've noticed a difference between 2.8 and 2.7, perhaps try to bake the same object with 2.79 to see if it makes a difference. If not, I guess you have no other solution than sculpt the high poly a bit more deeply so that the bumps of the normal will be more noticeable

Comment: @moonboots I’ll try with the math nodes, and sculpting deeper. That sounds like the best choice. Thank you for your help and going through that trouble. I appreciate it.

Comment: ok good luck   ;)

Comment: oh and put the Math (multiply) node between the Image Texture and the Bump node, not after the Bump node

Comment: Gotcha, I’ll try it. Thank you !